# Spring Boot 2.1.0, Jackson stopped deserializing Point class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

After upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.0 (from 2.0.x) my rest service doesn't work, when i trie to call it (with proper json):

> Type definition error: [simple type, class
>   org.springframework.data.geo.Point]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `org.springframework.data.geo.Point` (no
>   Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from
>   Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source:
>   UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
>   my.domain.Update[\"point\"])"

Update class:

```
@Document
public class Update {
    @JsonProperty
    private final double rangeInMeters;
    @JsonProperty("point")
    private final Point point;

    @JsonCreator
    public Update(@JsonProperty("rangeInMeters") double rangeInMeters, @JsonProperty("point") final Point point) {
        this.rangeInMeters = rangeInMeters;
        this.point = point;
    }
```

and the Point is:`org.springframework.data.geo.Point`

My Update JSON:

```
{
  "rangeInMeters": "100",
  "point": {
    "type" : "Point",
    "x": -1,
    "y": 2
  }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? it worked perfectly with previous Spring Boot.

Comment: The line `through reference chain: my.domain.Update[\"point\"]`of the stack trace suggests that Spring is may be trying to set the property directly. You could try using the [JsonIgnoreProperties Annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) with the point property.

Comment: but i want to set Point property and it worked before (maybe jakson version changed)

Comment: I think that what Jackson does it trying to create a point (`new Point()`) for later invoking its setters, but `Point` does not have an empty constructor.

I am not sure if it is a clean solution, but would you mind wrapping point in a class that has an empty constructor and setters and getters and delegate the work to a wrapped Point?

Comment: @razor Jackson should be able to deserialize this. Can you check if you have `jackson-module-parameter-names` artifact on your classpath and project is compiled with [parameters](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#parameters) set to `true`?

Comment: i have jackson-module-parameter-names:2.9.7
and i've added configuration/parameters: true to maven-compiler-plugin, but still the same error

Comment: i had to create my own custom deserialiser for Point class ...

Comment: @razor I am facing the same issue. Would you mind putting your fix as an answer to this question?